# Redirect before rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, symphony-cms

Had an issue where I need to redirect old URLs, but not disable the mod_rewrite for page structure.

```
redirect 301 /home.html http://www.url.com/
```

It needs to live on the Symphony 2.0 .htaccess file

```
### Symphony 2.0.x ###
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    ### DO NOT APPLY RULES WHEN REQUESTING "favicon.ico"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} favicon.ico [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [S=14]

    ### IMAGE RULES 
    RewriteRule ^image\/(.+\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp))$ extensions/jit_image_manipulation/lib/image.php?param=$1 [L,NC]

    ### CHECK FOR TRAILING SLASH - Will ignore files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

    ### ADMIN REWRITE
    RewriteRule ^symphony\/?$ index.php?mode=administration&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^symphony(\/(.*\/?))?$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&mode=administration&%{QUERY_STRING}   [NC,L]

    ### FRONTEND REWRITE - Will ignore files and folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*\/?)$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]

</IfModule>
######
```

Comment: Updated to reflect answer by @matt_asbury

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^home(.*) http://url.com/ [R=301,L]`